# Improve the quality of the letters in a image

Tags: python, image, opencv, letters

I'm working with images that have text. The problem is that these images are receipts, and after a lot of transformations, the text lost quality. 
I'm using python and opencv.
I was trying with a lot of combinations of morphological transformations from the doc [Morphological Transformations](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html), but I don't get satisfactory results.

I'm doing this right now (I'll comment what I've tried, and just let uncommented what I'm using):

```
kernel = np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8)
# opening = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
# closing = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
# dilation = cv2.dilate(opening, kernel, iterations=1)
# kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)
# gradient = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)
#
img = erosion.copy()
```

With this, from this original image:

[image]

I get this:

[image]

It's a little bit better, as you can see. But it still too bad. The OCR (tesseract) doesn't recognize the characters here very well. I've trained, but as you can note, every "e" is different, and so on.

I get good results, but I think, if I resolve this problem, they would be even better.

Maybe I can do another thing, or use a better combination of the morphological transformations. If there is another tool (PIL, imagemagick, etc..) that I could use, I can use it.

Here's the whole image, so you can see how it looks:

[image]

As I said, it's not so bad, but a little be more "optimization" of the letters would be perfect.

Comment: Try using a morphological closing instead of erosion. As for the letters, they seem to be different from the start so I think there is not much you can do with just easy algorithms. Some scanners replace similar letters with the exact same bitmap, so maybe you can replicate this behaviour. But beware: there was a very ugly bug in Xerox machines that made the lives of librarians very uncomfortable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After years working in this theme, I can tell now, that what I wanted to do take a big effort, it's quite slow, and NEVER worked as I expected. The irregularities of the pixels in the characters are always unpredictable, that's why "easy algorithms" don't work.

Question: It's impossible then to have a decent OCR, which can read damaged characters?

Answer: No, it's not impossible. But it takes "a bit" more than just using erosion, morphological closing or something like that.

Then, how? Neural Networks :)

Here are two amazing papers that help me a lot:

[Can we build language-independent OCR using LSTM networks?](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/260341307_Can_we_build_language-independent_OCR_using_LSTM_networks)

[Reading Scene Text in Deep Convolutional Sequences](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.04395v2.pdf)

And for those who aren't familiar with RNN, I can suggest this:

[Understanding LSTM Networks](https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/)

There's also a python library, which works pretty good (and unfortunately even better for C++):

[ocropy](https://github.com/tmbdev/ocropy)

I really hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider the neighboring pixels and add sum of them.

For example:

```
n = numpy.zeros((3,3))
s = numpy.zeros((3,3))
w = numpy.zeros((3,3))
e = numpy.zeros((3,3))

n[0][1] = 1
s[2][1] = 1
w[1][0] = 1
e[1][2] = 1

img_n = cv2.erode(img, n, iterations=1)
img_s = cv2.erode(img, s, iterations=1)
img_w = cv2.erode(img, w, iterations=1)
img_e = cv2.erode(img, e, iterations=1)

result = img_n + img_s + img_w + img_e + img
```

Also, you can either numpy or cv2 to add the arrays.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look for _a neighboring pixel algorithm_  or so. 
But in the answer you proposed me, I think that with `n[4]` you mean `n[1][0]` or? As n is a matrix with 3 rows and 3 cols.
However, it's not working. _result_ looks exactly as _img_. Maybe something should be changed.

Comment: Updated the answer with modified masks. It is basically 'n' takes more weightage on north direction, 's' takes more weightage on south direction and so on. Can you increase the size of convolution mask and try it.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience erode impairs OCR quality. If you have grayscale image (not binary) you can use better binarization algorithm. I use SAUVOLA algorithm for binarization.  If you have only binary image the best thing you can do is removing the noise (remove all small dots).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
How do you use Sauvola? With Leptonica? I use the otsu binarization proposed in OpenCV, but could also test it with Sauvola if I find how implement (or use) it on python.

Comment: I use c++ implementation of SAUVOLA algorithm. https://github.com/benob/opencv-utils/blob/master/include/binarize.h

Also you can try to use MEAN's adaptiveThreshold (http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html). This binarization shows similar result like SAUVOLA.

Answer (score 0):

I found the [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) I'm trying to implement it for closed polygons in Haskell. Maybe it can solve something.